# WPF Toolkit DataGrid how do I set Column Header SelectionBackground?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

I would just like to change the background of the column headers in the datagrid to Blue with White text.  I was finally able to but the Mouse Over and Selection styles for the Column Header change the background to White.  As you can imagine White text on a White Background won't do.

For some reason this has been the most absurdly difficult thing to change.

I tried using Styles: (had no effect)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:ColumnManagerCell}">
            <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#475463" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" /> 
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Style>
```

I tried doing it in the Grid itself (just throws an error)

```
 <xcdg:DataGridControl ....
 <xcdg:ColumnManagerCell SelectionBackground="Black"></xcdg:ColumnManagerCell>
```

What magical incantation is required to perform the simple task of altering the hover background color on these cells???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `Background` is not handled by the `ColumnManagerCell` itself but a `Border` inside it.

Reaching it is at best difficult so if your only concern is readability then just set the `Foreground` using a `Trigger`:

```
<Style TargetType="xcdg:ColumnManagerCell">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#475463" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You could also change the whole **template**, it's up to you to tell if it's worth the pain...